# I have a problem unable to send RTMP with egress

Tags: egress, livekit

I'm trying to use Egress to send RTMP from livekit.
detail
livekist-server:v1.5.0
egress:v1.7.9
run on docker 2 vm
i trying testing send RTMP to youtube
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktrgz.png)

I don't understand where I misconfigured it. Or what do I need to fix?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zABiD.jpg)

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is that I config api_key and api_secret incorrectly, which makes it impossible to connect to the livekit server as Mr. Frostbyte recommends.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Your Egress is likely not configured properly to connect to LiveKit server. `ws_url` must be set to a publicly reachable address to your LiveKit server. i.e. `wss://my.livekit.host`

Comment: I have already configured ws_url as wss://meet-lab.one.th but Mr. Frostbyte has suggested a problem saying chrome: END_RECORDING was sent due to no available tracks in the room, closing the egress. I'm not sure where I need to start. Where do you go to check the problem? I've added my config in the attached picture.